# How does one win 2048 - Multiplayer

Tags: 2048

[Emil Stolarsky](https://emil.dev) made a [multiplayer version](https://emil.dev/2048-multiplayer) of the popular game [2048](https://play2048.co). I have played it many times, but I still can't figure out how to win. It's not based directly off of highest score, biggest tile, fastest to get to a certain score/tile, etc. Sometimes even *both* players win.

Does anyone know how to win at 2048—Multiplayer?

Comment: http://emils.github.io/2048-multiplayer/ is 404 now.   There's a version at https://emil.dev/2048-multiplayer/  which might be the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to take your time, the winner can be the person who doesn't get game over first.

I've only played it once, but I noticed that the opponent I played with was very fast, but they lost, even with a higher score, because they got "game over" while I was still playing and thinking about what to do, I wasn't particularly slow, just taking my time.

My advice: Don't rush.

Comment: Oh, duh. I feel stupid now. I think that can explain about every time the person with the highest score doesn't win. Thanks!

Comment: While it is possible to trigger an early loss with a game over, there is some other win condition. See [this game](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQbQ.png), for example.

Comment: @bob: There is currently (not sure if it is new since your post) a 2 minute time limit. Highest score at the end wins.

Comment: @Chris That explains it. So, don't rush too much but you can't really take your time either :(

Comment: If you just use the left/down trick you can rush quite a lot. :)

Comment: @Chris I tend to go right